# Run php script from command line with variable

Tags: php, command-line

I want to run a PHP script from the command line, but I also want to set a variable for that script.

Browser version: `script.php?var=3`

Command line: `php -f script.php`  (but how do I give it the variable containing 3?)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Script:**

```
<?php

// number of arguments passed to the script
var_dump($argc);

// the arguments as an array. first argument is always the script name
var_dump($argv);
```

**Command:**

```
$ php -f test.php foo bar baz
int(4)
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "test.php"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "baz"
}
```

Also, take a look at [using PHP from the command line](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php).

Comment: works fine... other answers would work too but this was first and does make it look better than having a long list of variable names and data.

Answer (score 6):

Besides argv (as Ionut mentioned), you can use environment variables:

E.g.:

```
var = 3 php -f test.php
```

In test.php:

```
$var = getenv("var");
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to keep named parameters almost like var=3&foo=bar (instead of the positional parameters offered by [$argv](http://de.php.net/cli)) [getopt()](http://uk.php.net/getopt) can assist you.

Answer (score 4):

As well as using [argc](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argc.php) and [argv](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) as indicated by [Ionut G. Stan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974356/run-php-script-from-command-line-with-variable/974362#974362), you could also use the PEAR module [Console_Getopt](http://pear.php.net/package/Console_Getopt) which can parse out unix-style command line options. See [this article](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1046) for more information.

Alternatively, there's similar functionality in the Zend Framework in the [Zend_Console_Getopt](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.console.getopt.html) class.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of solutions put the arguments into variables according to their order. For example,

```
myfile.php 5 7
```

will put the 5 into the first variable and 7 into the next variable.

I wanted named arguments:

```
myfile.php  a=1 x=8
```

so that I can use them as variable names in the PHP code.

The link that Ionuț G. Stan gave at
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

gave me the answer.

sep16 at psu dot edu:

You can easily parse command line arguments into the $_GET variable by using the parse_str() function.

```
<?php
parse_str(implode('&', array_slice($argv, 1)), $_GET);
?>
```

It behaves exactly like you'd expect with cgi-php.

```
$ php -f somefile.php a=1 b[]=2 b[]=3
```

This will set $_GET['a'] to '1' and $_GET['b'] to array('2', '3').

Comment: IMPORTANT: Must use `if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli')` before of `parse_str` function, because does not overwrite `$_GET` when use on web.