# PHP: Is it possible to do a task on the server without the user noticing a difference in load time?

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

I've got a form upload where I'm adding user's input to the database. As part of the process I also send an email to myself with an attachment of a file (that the user uploaded).

The code structure is quite simple:

```
//Establishing the $_POST[] vars
//Log them in DB
// Send out the email <-- This part adds 5 seconds to load time!!
//Redirect user to a success page
```

The bit where I send the email to myself makes up a 5 second difference to the load time between when the user hits 'Submit' and sees the 'Success' page!!

The code for sending out the email looks like this:

```
$to = "test@test.com";
$subject = "new Image";
require_once('../api/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = $smtp_host;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = $smtp_host;
$mail->Port       = $smpt_port;
$mail->Username   = $smpt_email_username;
$mail->Password   = $smpt_email_pass;
$mail->AddAddress($to, '');
$mail->SetFrom($set_from_email, $set_from_name);
$mail->AddReplyTo($replyto_email, $replyto_name);
$mail->Subject = "new image";
$mail->AltBody = $mail_altbody;
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('../uploads/'.$image, 't');
$mail->IsHTML(true);               
$mail->MsgHTML('<img src="cid:t" />');
$mail->Send();
```

My question is - is it possible to send the email asynchronously, so it can take place in the server by itself, eliminating the need for the user to wait for the additional time while the email is being sent?

Thanks!

Comment: Redirect the User from the form to another "thank-you" page (or whatever you use). In the end of that (so after all your displaystuff), you include the php-file above. Then the user sees the page while the webserver is still busy with sending the mail. I think that will work, but not completely sure.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can create queue of emails in database table and send all emails from queue with cron job. Cron job can be run every minute.

2) You can directly create another php process in non blocking mode. This process performs all work with smtp

```
shell_exec("nohup php /path/to/script.php arg1 arg2 arg3 > /dev/null & echo $!");
```

[Run php script from command line with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974356/run-php-script-from-command-line-with-variable)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use a PHP Fork module. I think it's a bit better than the usage of exec().

PHP (>= 5.3) Pcntl fork:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php

You will still have a higher load on your machine while sending your mail, but it isn't the same process anymore. That will be another PID.