# PHP CLI: how to handle unnamed argument

Tags: php

In a PHP script to use from the command line:

As far as I understand, the function getopt() only allows to process 'named' arguments, eg.: `$args = getopt("h:m:");`   would allow to run the script with the defined arguments like this:

```
  ./script.php -h24 -m60;
```

but how to get the first (second, third...) unnamed argument, e.g.:

```
 ./script  -h24 -m60 additional_argument_1 "argument 2";
```

`$_SERVER['argv']` allows to get all arguments but depending on the number of (optional) named arguments used, it's not straightforward to get the first unnamed argument.

How can I easily get the value of additional_argument_1 and of an optional second unnamed argument?

Comment: The magic `$argv` array contains all the arguments passed to your script. You could try filtering out the options however I'd be more inclined to not re-invent the wheel and use an off-the-shelf solution like [symfony/console](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would combine getopt with argv. This will give you a good start:

```
<?php

print_r($argc);
print_r($argv);

$getopt = getopt("a::b::c::");

$optionals = array();

// Get all arguments delivered
foreach ($argv as $key1=>$value1) {
    // Skip the filename
    if ($key1 == 0) {
        continue;
    }

    $match = false;
    // Compare to each argument recognized by getopt
    foreach ($getopt as $key2=>$value2) {
        if ("-".$key2.$value2 === $value1 || "--".$key2.$value2 === $value1) {
            $match = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    // If it was not recognized by getopt, it is an optional. Keep it.
    if (!$match) {
        $optionals[] = $value1;
    }
}

print_r($optionals);

?>
```

You can start it with:

```
php getopt.php -aarg -c optional1 optional2 optional3
```

It will answer:

```
Array
(
    [0] => optional1
    [1] => optional2
    [2] => optional3
)
```

Further, here are same very interesting suggestions:
[Run php script from command line with variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974356/run-php-script-from-command-line-with-variable/974374)

But you might want to rethink your design with several unnamed options. Also, the example code could be refactored into an enhanced usage of PHP array functions with callbacks, or extract the inner loop into a function. But it's a good start.

Comment: It seems a bit overcomplicated to me.

Comment: Oh, well. I think that this is the only way to do it if you do not use the `--name=value` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can simply look for arguments in `$argv` that does not start with a dash:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Get all arguments that does not start with - or --
 *
 * @return array
 */
function unnamed_arguments() {
    $args = [];
    foreach( $GLOBALS[ 'argv' ] as $arg ) {
        if( '-' !== $arg[ 0 ] ) {
            $args[] = $arg;
        }
    }
    array_shift( $args ); // discard the name of your script
    return $args;
}

var_dump( unnamed_arguments() );
```

*Note*: You can't use this method if you have other stuff with values like `--name value`. For arguments with values you should use the syntax `--name=value` instead.